# Latest mysql-5.5.53 update seems to have broken

Tags: 14.04, server, mysql

I'm currently running Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS (GNU/Linux 4.4.0-45-generic x86_64)
and just installed the update these packages yesterday.

mysql-common all 5.5.53-0ubuntu0.14.04.1
libmysqlclient18 amd64 5.5.53-0ubuntu0.14.04.1
mysql-server all 5.5.53-0ubuntu0.14.04.1
 mysql-server-5.5 amd64 5.5.53-0ubuntu0.14.04.1
mysql-client all 5.5.53-0ubuntu0.14.04.1
 mysql-client-5.5 amd64 5.5.53-0ubuntu0.14.04.1
 mysql-client-core-5.5 amd64 5.5.53-0ubuntu0.14.04.1
 mysql-server-core-5.5 amd64 5.5.53-0ubuntu0.14.04.1

After update, I've got error.

```
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/lib/mysql/mysqld.sock' (13)
```

So, What should I do? I want to rollback MySQL 5.5.53 to 5.5.52!!

please, Help me!!

Comment: solusion: sudo chmod 755 -R /var/lib/MySQL

Comment: Please don't add "solved" to a title. If you have a solution, consider posting it as an answer instead.

Answer (score 0):

solution:

sudo chmod 755 -R /var/lib/mysql

Answer (score 0):

It is looking for directory mysql-files in `/var/lib`
Please create it manually over there by using below commands and then restart your mysql.

```
sudo mkdir /var/lib/mysql-files
sudo chown -R mysql:mysql /var/lib/mysql-files/
sudo chmod 700 /var/lib/mysql-files/
```

See [this Launchpad bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/mysql-5.5/+bug/1637280) for more details.